# Java TCP/IP: HTTP-Connection to Livestream

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, live-streaming

I can connect to a HTTP-Livestream manually by using Sockets like that:

```
Socket radio = new Socket();
radio.connect(new InetSocketAddress("streaming.fueralle.org", 8000));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(radio.getOutputStream());
out.println("GET /corax.mp3 HTTP/1.0");
out.println("User-Agent: Wget/1.8.2");
out.println("Host: streaming.fueralle.org:8000");
out.println("Accept: */*");
out.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
out.println("");
out.flush();

DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(radio.getInputStream());
String headerLine = is.readLine();
while(headerLine.length() > 0){
    resp.getWriter().println("next line is " + headerLine);
    headerLine = is.readLine();
}
```

Now I have to do this connection with URL and HttpUrlConnection instead (I plan to run it from Google App Engine, which allows no Socket). But I seem to be missing an important bit. If I try a static page like heise.de, it works. But I can not start reading a continuous Stream.

EDIT2:
I have put the source (and the whole project) in github, do I miss a big thing? https://github.com/flaschenpost/GoogleAppRadio/blob/master/MGRadio/src/de/gergele/mgradio/MGRadioServlet.java

Here a snippet.

```
URL u = new URL("http://streaming.fueralle.org:8000/corax.mp3");
// URL u = new URL("http://www.heise.de");
System.out.println("trying to connect!" + u);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MGet/1.0.0");
conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
// conn.addRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
// EDIT: I tried with and without setChunkedStreamingMode, I hoped it would 
//       tell the connection-object about the streaming mode from the server
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(4096);
System.out.println("setup finished..." + conn + " " + conn.getRequestProperties().toString());
System.out.println(" type: " + conn.getContentType());

DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```

But that leads to an TimeoutException before reading a single character from the headers.

So now my question: Howo can I tune the HTTP-Connection to be as successfull as the Socket-Connection? Do I really have to write my own URLStreamHandlerFactory? Sounds a bit weird...

wget and curl get that stream easily, and I have already spent half a night to find out that Java URL seems to contain to much magic somehow for those livestreams.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is `conn.setChunketStreamMode(4096);` really needed? You see, `GET` requests MUST NOT have a body — but if they do, servers will wait for it to arrive to discard it.

Comment: I tried it with and without ChunkedStremMode, I thought it could give a hint to javas URL-Handling not to wait for a Content-Size from Server. Though it didn't work neither with or without it. :-(

Comment: Well, I commented out `conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(4096);`, and the second code, with appended `String headerLine = is.readLine(); while(headerLine.length() > 0){ system.out.println("next line is " + headerLine); headerLine = is.readLine(); }`, works just fine: it writes a ton of noise to the console.

Comment: Strange... I will try a POJO-Version but I cannot imagine that the context changes so much. I have added the full source in my original Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use google app engine for live streaming. GAE framework has a time restriction on servlet execution time [proof](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_request_timer). If you go for background tasks (backend in gae) you will have to pay. And still you'll be only able to save the stream, not to stream it live.

Comment: So I should not try to let it run in a Servlet. Thanks for that comment. So it really goes into programming the ARM in my Network box.